# Is there a way to download file from remote server with custom user agent without cUrl in PHP5

Tags: php, curl

Right now i have this (and it works on my localhost):

```
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 30;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd()."/cacert.pem");
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
return (string)$data;
```

}

But my web server doesn't allow me to use cUrl. How can i rewrite this code in php that it won't use cUrl?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are http clients written in "pure php", like https://github.com/hightman/httpclient

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
 $opt = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (K ..."
   "ssl"=>array(
    "cafile" => "/path-to-cacert/cacert.pem",
    "verify_peer"=> true,
    "verify_peer_name"=> true,
),
 )
);


$file = file_get_contents('https://www.example.com/', false, stream_context_create($opts));
```

see

- http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php